# Reading a text file till EOF in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a text file which has -

> hello James!
>
> How are you today!

I am using the below code:

```
int readedValue;

do
{   
    while((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != 10)
   {
    //readedValue = bufferReader.read();
    char ch = (char) readedValue;
    System.out.print(ch);
   } 

}
while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1);
```

When I read the file now, I get output as hello James!ow are you today!

I am not getting 'H'ow in How. How can I alter this to get the complete text?

Comment: what about `BufferedReader` class?!

Comment: Google for "java read file line by line" and you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one...

```
int readedValue;

while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1)
{   
    if(readedValue  != 10)
    {
         System.out.print((char) readedValue);
   } 

}
```

Comment: The `char` representation of `10` is `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You're losing a character in your `do-while` loop's conditions

```
do {
    ...
    // ends when the first new line \n character is reached
}
while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1);
        ^ never printed 
// the character that isn't read is the first character after the \n, ie. 'H'
```

Use a single loop that stores the `readedValue` (readValue) and does any comparison on that one.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are reading a character twice when linefeed is encountered ascii 10

```
do
{   
    while((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != 10) // Here 
   {
    //readedValue = bufferReader.read();
    char ch = (char) readedValue;
    System.out.print(ch);
   } 

}
while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1); // Again here
```

What you should do is read it only once

```
while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1)
{   
    if(readedValue != 10) 
   {
    char ch = (char) readedValue;
    System.out.print(ch);
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you:

```
String line;
int readedValue;
String s = "hello James!\n\rHow are you today!";
StringReader input = new StringReader(s);
BufferedReader lineReader= new BufferedReader (input);

while((line=lineReader.readLine())!=null) {
    StringReader input2 = new StringReader(line);
    BufferedReader charReader= new BufferedReader (input2);
    while((readedValue = charReader.read()) != -1) {
        char ch = (char) readedValue;
        System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
```